# Use a variable returned by Get-Variable

Tags: powershell

Hopefully this answer isn't above me. I've created a custom object with properties and methods.  I create several of them on the fly, depending on what the user selects at the beginning.

So for this example, the script might create $PRD1, $PRD2, $TST1 and $TST4.

$PRD1, $PRD2, $TST1 and $TST4 will have some properties like DebugMode, DisableAppsStartTime, DisableAppsStopTime.  They'll have some methods like DisableApps(), EnableApps().

How can I find out which variables the script ended up creating?  I can use Get-Variable to know the ones it created (plus I DO still have the initial list of names to create).  My issue is that I'm having trouble figuring out to call the ones I've created, in a manner that allows me to use the methods and properties, without a ridiculous mash up of nested foreach/if/switch commands.

I certainly hope that made sense.

Thanks in advance,
SS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I DO still have the initial list of names to create

Assuming that `$list` contains this list, the following creates an (ordered) hash table of those variables that were actually created from that list:

```
$variableMap = [ordered] @{}
(Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore -Scope Local $list).
  ForEach({ $variableMap[$_.Name] = $_.Value })
```

Note: `-Scope Local` limits the lookup to the *current* scope<sup>[1]</sup>; omit it to target all variables visible in the current scope, which includes those from ancestral (parent) scopes.

You can then loop over `$variableMap.Keys` to process them all, or access one by name selectively, e.g., `$variableMap.PRD1` (or `$variableMap['PRD1']`).

You then use regular dot notation to access properties and methods of these entries; e.g., `$variableMap.PRD1.DisableApps()`.

---

<sup>[1] This includes variables created with the `AllScope` option, e.g., `$HOME`, because they are copied to *every* scope, as the name suggests. You can find all such variables with

`Get-Variable | Where-Object Options -match 'AllScope'`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with the `where-object` cmdlet and the `-like` operator with an foreach loop.

```
foreach($var in (get-variable | Where-object {$_.name -like '*PRD*' -or $_.name -like '*TST*'})){
    $var
}
```